# Passing a guid as a crm filter option

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to use a GUID field from CRM4 database via a WSDL query but I am unsure as to how to pass multiple guid values into the database, if I try to do this it results in an error:

**`0x80040216`
An unexpected error occurred.
Platform**

The code that I am passing in is as follows:

```
Dim cond2 As CrmService.ConditionExpression = New CrmService.ConditionExpression
cond2.Operator = CrmService.ConditionOperator.In
cond2.AttributeName = "createdby"
cond2.Values = {"3398448B-D65B-E611-95A2-000D3AB23B6B", "1196E35B-E05B-E611-95A2-000D3AB23B6B"}
```

Any idea as to what might be causing this error and how I can correctly pass multiple guid values into the condition values.

I have also tried:

```
cond2.Values = {New Guid("3398448B-D65B-E611-95A2-000D3AB23B6B"), New Guid("1196E35B-E05B-E611-95A2-000D3AB23B6B")}
```

And also:

```
Dim testGuid As New UniqueIdentifier
testGuid.Value = New Guid("1196E35B-E05B-E611-95A2-000D3AB23B6B")
testGuid.IsNull = False
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at table valued parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx Any other method of passing multiple values gets kind of ugly. You either would need dynamic sql or a string splitter.

Answer (score 0):

Try building an array first defined as type of Guid.

```
Dim values As Guid() = New Guid() {a_guid, another_guid}
Dim c As New ConditionExpression("createdby", ConditionOperator.[In], values)
```

Comment: The first line is throwing an error that string cannot be converted to GUID

Comment: what does "name relate to"? I have restructured this as follows: im guidValues As Guid() = New Guid(2) {}
            guidValues(1) = New Guid("3398448B-D65B-E611-95A2-000D3AB23B6B")
            guidValues(2) = New Guid("1196E35B-E05B-E611-95A2-000D3AB23B6B")

Comment: @Jay, Updated my answer, `name` should be your attribute, e.g. `createdby`. The array should be of `Guid` values not `string` as you mentioned.